# How to define the out_channel in nn.Conv2d?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am a beginner in deep learning,when i use conv2d in nn,I have a question
As we all know the kernal size,stride,padding depends on input size and output size what we want,
in channel usually is the input image size or the last conv2d outchannel,
But! What the out channels to select ,Such as the first step in AlexNet:

> nn.Conv2d(1, 96, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=1)

the conv is to convert 224*224 pic to 54*54,but why select 96 to out channel,I have no idea

I tried to search in Internet,but doest have the satisfied answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pytorch Conv2d Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d)
The documentation shows, nn.Conv2d has following

```
torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros', device=None, dtype=None)
```

So, the first argument you pass is in_channels i.e.,1 in your case.
The second argument is 96 i.e., out_channels.

There is no fixed or 100% pure shot way to find the number of out_channels, it is usually found by a lot of experimentation and tweaking.

Comment: tks, the answer helps me :)